# How to bind event handler function dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, say I have a very simple case:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var Todo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>Hello there 
            <button id="switch_func">Switch</button>
        </div>);
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("div1"));
```

What I am trying to bind is:

There are multiple handler functions, each time when that button switch_func gets clicked, it will randomly choose another handlers and bind to itself.

But I do not know how to bind it like in AngularJS or jQuery, cos I am not sure if I can do same thing to the virtual DOM:

```
$("button#switch_func").on("click", function(){
    $(this).off("click");
    $(this).on("click", anotherHandler);
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to unbind and rebind the same event type? Just put `aRandomHandler()` inside the `anotherHandler` function...

Comment: @David thanks, I do not quite get your idea, could you show me a little code snippet? What I want is totally change the click handler function

Comment: Instead of changing the handler function, you can change a function *inside* the handler function: `.on('click', function() { randomFunction() })`

Comment: @David Thanks, but how do I replace the body of click handler function, all the handler functions are outside, I can only use them. Do you mean I need to set case selection for different handler? But in that case, It means I need to know what function I have, right?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/tj4rw78j/

Answer (score 0):

To bind functions you can use `onClick` 
Simply put

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Switch</button>
```

And handle the *click* event on the component's function:

```
var Todo = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(){
        //put your function here!
    },
    //other functions in your component (e.g. render, getInitialState, etc)

});
```

Comment: Thanks, so this means each time I click the button, React probably need to render the button again?

Comment: @Kuan I believe I didn't quite get your question. Maybe you should take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845910/how-do-i-set-state-of-sibling-components-easily-in-react