# ReactJS: setState from outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Tools from './components/class/Tools'
import Loading from './components/inc/Loading'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Tools.showLoading();
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Loading />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Loading.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="loading" style={{display: this.state.display}}>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want change `display` of `Loading` from `Tools.js`:

```
export default class Tools extends React.Component {
    static showLoading(){ // or non-static
        Loading.setState ...
    }
}
```

How I can access and setState variable from another class or function or outside?

Comment: See also: [How do I set state of sibling components easily in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30845910/1218980)

Comment: If your `Tools` need to directly access `Loading`, then your component is not very reusable since `Tools` only works if it has access to a `Loading` component.

Comment: Other example: [What's the right way to pass form element state to sibling/parent elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24147331/1218980)

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm so sorry. components are not sibling. i edit my question. please check again

Answer (score 1):

Your `Loading` and `Tools` components are siblings, so it is harder to pass data between them.

You should pull the state out to the parent `App` component, then you can pass in the `setState` callback method and the `state.loading` variable into the `Tool` and `Loading` components as a prop.

---

Or you can re-use your Loading component within all the other components, like so:

```
export default class Tool extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            loading: true
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Loading isloading={loading}>
            <div>
            // content here
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. components are not sibling. i edit my question. please check again

Comment: You can't just call a static method from a non-mounted React.Component class, I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I have ye loading componenet. this component use whole project and i want every where and every time change this display. i dont want duplicate codes. Generally, i want create loading and use it repeatedly every where. (app.js, components, classes or ... )